# Service modules-init-tools not found

Tags: kernel, services, fancontrol, lm-sensors

While setting up lm-sensors and fanconrtol packages on Ubuntu 13.04, I arrived at a stage were I had to restart the service modules-init-tools to apply changes to the /etc/modules file then alas! I got "modules-init-tools: unrecognized service". I know a reboot of the system will most likely apply the changes. But I want to know where the service is or if it has been replaced how do I restart it from terminal without doing a reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"modules-init-tools" is not a service, it is a package that provides commmands to manage kernel modules.

The commands inside this package are lsmod, modprobe, rmmod, etc.

Put that, what makes sense is if you need to restart a module, and not a service with "modules-init-tools".

Just for information, "modules-init-tools" was replaced by "kmod" recently in 13.10, and I am not sure if for 13.04, but kept compatibility with previous commands and you can use, if it is the case in 13.04, 'rmmod' and 'modprobe' as before. No changes to the syntaxe!

Answer (score 1):

Although module-init-tools is a package, it also provides a service, such that you could automatically load modules configured in `/etc/modules` by running

```
service module-init-tools start
```

As @vitorafsr explained, module-init-tools has been replaced with kmod. Fortunately, kmod also provides a service, so after editing `/etc/modules`, you can run

```
service kmod start
```